# Take the first unique value form a function

Tags: r

This is my function:

```
g <- function(x,y){
   x <- (x-y):x
   y <- 1:30 # ------> (y is always fixed 1:30)
   z<- outer(x,y,fv) # ---->(fv is a previous function)
   s <- colSums(z)
   which(s==max(s),arr.ind=T)
}
```

It tells me the position of the max value in s.                                                                       I basically have a problem in choosing y because given a small y, the max(s) appears more than once in s. For example:

```
#given x=53 
> g(53,1)
[1] 13 16 20 22 25 26 27 
> g(53,2)
[1] 20 25 26
> g(53,3)
[1] 20 25 26
> g(53,4)
[1] 20 25 26
> g(53,5)
[1] 20 25
> g(53,6) 
[1] 25   -----> This is the only result i would like from my function (right y=6)
```

Another example:

```
# given x=71
> g(71,1)
[1] 7 9 14 
> g(71,2)
[1] 7 14
> g(71,3)
[1] 14 -----> my desired result (right y=3)
```

Therefore, i would like a function resulting in the first unique solution given y as small as possible ( ex: `g(53)=25 , g(71)=14, ...`). Any help? Thanks

This is a simplify example. I hope to be more clear in questioning:

```
#The idea is the same:

n <- 1:9
e <- rep(nn,500)
p<- sample(e)   # --->(Need to sample in order to have more max later (mixed matrix)
mat <- matrix(p,90)

g <- function(x,y){
x <- (x-y):x
k <- rowSums(mat[,x])
which(k==max(k), arr.ind=T)
}

#In my sample matrix :

k <- rowSums(mat[,44:45])
which(k==max(k), arr.ind=T)
[1] 44 71 90
#In fact
g(45,1)
[1] 44 71 90  # ---> more than one solution

g(45,2)
[1] 90  # ----> I would like to pick up this value wich is the first unique solution given x=45
```

Therefore, i would like a function resulting in the first unique solution for y as small as possible given x ( in this new ex: `g(45)=90`... ).

Comment: We need a reproducible example, can you give us also `fv` function ?

Comment: Anyway, I suspect you can simply use `which.max(s)` or `which(s==max(s))[1]` ...

Comment: Thanks, but this does not solve my problem. It just picks up the first one. I made a new example, hope to be more clear.

Comment: You need a function that keeps increasing `y` until it finds a result whose `length` is one. So, use an `if/else` statement that checks the length of your `which` statement. If the length is 1, return the result. Otherwise, increase `y` by one and call `g` again.

Comment: @Albert:  when you post a reproducible example using some random function (e.g. sample in your case), you should use `set.seed(someFixedNumber)` at the beginning of your script. In fact if I run your case I get other numbers...anyway I guess you have your solution now...

Answer (score 1):

I got it. It is a bit long but i think right.

Taking into consideration the second simplify example:

```
 g <- function(x,y){
 x <- (x-y):x
 k <- rowSums(mat[,x])
 q <- which(k==max(k), arr.ind=T)
 length(q)
 }

 gv <- Vectorize(g)

 l <- function(x){
 y<- 1:30 # <- (until 30 to be sure)
 z<- outer(x,y,gv)
 y <- which.min(z) # <- (min is surely length=1 and which.min takes the first)
 x <- (x-y):x
 k <- rowSums(mat[,x])
 q <- which(k==max(k), arr.ind=T)
 q
 }

 l(45)
 [1] 90
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you could just do this with a [recursive function](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~calvin/cs110/RECURSION.html). Consider the following:

```
set.seed(42)
n = 1:9
e = rep(n, 500)
p = sample(e)
mat = matrix(p, 90)

g <- function(x, y=1) {
  xv <- (x-y):x
  k <- rowSums(mat[, xv])
  i <- which(k == max(k), arr.ind=T)
  n <- length(i)
  if (n == 1) {
    return(y) # want to know the min y that solves the problem, right?
  } else {
    y <- y + 1 # increase y by 1
    g(x,y)  # run our function again with a new value of y
  }
}
```

You should now be able to run `g(45)` and get 1 as the result, since that is the value of `y` that solves the problem, and `g(33)` to get 2.